# CodeIgniter .htaccess / Mod_rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

In the past I have solved this problem by creating a new rule for every single controller.
So here we go;
By default the url is as below;

```
http://www.url.com/index.php/controller/method/parameters
```

I want to change this to;

```
http://www.url.com/controller/method/parameter1/parameter2/parameter3/etc...
```

My problem is the parameters-part as I sometimes have 3 or 4 parameters, but sometimes none or just one.

Right now I have this (which does not work, otherwise I wouldn't post):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

If I request just the controller it works (since an index() method is present), but custom methods and parameters do not work.

Then, do I also have to add routes to the config/routes.php?
In the past I fixed this problem by adding custom routes and rules for every single used combination.

I google'd for days, no success. Please tell me if I missed a post.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
```

That does the trick for me (note ? instead of / ), using `$config['uri_protocol']   = 'REQUEST_URI';` in the config file.

Comment: Do you also add routes? I seem to got it working by having only that rule and adding routes separately for every controller/method/parameter.

Comment: Yes, I do, e.g. `$route['controller/(:num)/(:any)'] = "controller/index/$1/$2";` where (:num) would be an integer (id) mapped to the database and (:any) would refer to a slug.

Comment: Also note: a URL with a controller method other than "index" will not require a custom route with this scheme, e.g. `example.com/controller/view/1/abc-de` will work right out of the box without the need for a custom route. I'll then just access parameters via `$this->uri->segment(3)` and `$this->uri->segment(4)`

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to change your URL structure, this will require the least amount of configuration:

Use a structure like         `http://www.url.com/controller/method/param1_key/param1_value/param2_key/param2_value/etc...`

Then, you can use `$this->uri->uri_to_assoc()` to get the key => value pairs in an associative array.

See the docs here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html